# VBA sql string error: missing operator

Tags: sql, vba

Writing an sql string in vba and getting syntax error for a missing operator. I thought the error was with the inner joins so I tried taking them out but still same error.

Here is the query string:

```
sql1 = "SELECT WorkOrder.ProjectID, tref_dep.department, live_project.project_codename " _
     & "FROM WorkOrder " _
     & "INNER JOIN tlive_project " _
     & "ON tlive_project.project_id = WorkOrder.ProjectID " _
     & "INNER JOIN tref_dep " _
     & "ON tref_dep.dep_id = WorkOrder.ToDepartment " _
     & "WHERE WorkOrder.ToDepartment = " & rs1!wo_depart_id & " AND WorkOrder.ProjectID = " & rs1!proj_id _
     & " CONTAINS(WorkOrder.WorkOrderDescription, 'TimeForce Upload,') " _
     & "LIMIT 1"
```

I am probably missing something simple but any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten a logic operator before `CONTAINS(..)` :

```
 & "WHERE WorkOrder.ToDepartment = " & rs1!wo_depart_id & " AND WorkOrder.ProjectID = " & rs1!proj_id _
 & "AND CONTAINS(WorkOrder.WorkOrderDescription, 'TimeForce Upload,') " _
 & "LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: Thanks @notulysses for the quick reply. I should have been more specific in my post but, `rs1!wo_depart_id` and `rs1!proj_id` are integers so I don't think I need the single quotes around them.

Comment: @Rob : have you succeeded?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Found out in VBA if you have 2 or more JOIN clauses you have to put a parenthesis around each individual clause.  That was where I was getting my error. I have updated with answer

Answer (score 0):

VBA requires parenthesis for 2 or more JOIN clauses.

```
sql1 = "SELECT WorkOrder.ProjectID, tref_dep.department, live_project.project_codename " _
 & "FROM (WorkOrder " _
 & "INNER JOIN tlive_project " _
 & "ON tlive_project.project_id = WorkOrder.ProjectID) " _
 & "INNER JOIN tref_dep " _
 & "ON tref_dep.dep_id = WorkOrder.ToDepartment " _
 & "WHERE WorkOrder.ToDepartment = " & rs1!wo_depart_id & " AND WorkOrder.ProjectID = " & rs1!proj_id _
 & " CONTAINS(WorkOrder.WorkOrderDescription, 'TimeForce Upload,') " _
 & "LIMIT 1"
```